Relationship between presheaf morphism and sheafification.
Let $X$ be a topological space. $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are presheaves on $X$, $\mathcal{F}^{\#}$ and $\mathcal{G}^{\#}$ are sheafification of $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$. Let $\varphi: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ be morphism of presheaves. $\varphi^{\#}: \mathcal{F}^{\#} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}^{\#}$ is induced by $\varphi$. What is the relationship between $\ker(\varphi)$ $Im(\varphi)$ and $\ker(\varphi^{\#})$ $Im(\varphi^{\#})$. Is it a sheafification relationship? How to prove it? 
My attempt: Let $i_{1}: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}^{\#}$, then I can prove
$i_{1}(\ker(\varphi(U))) \subseteq \ker(\varphi^{\#}(U))$ for any open set $U \subseteq X$. Bet I have no idea about the follow-up and $Im$ situation.

Hint: Check that sheafification is an exact functor, and that exact functors preserve kernels and cokernels.
